# Transistor as an amplifier

Tags: circuit-analysis, amplifier

I'm currently working on this circuit and it appears that my output voltage is not showing the correct values for the positive half wave .

For starters I have these values below  - \$U_{CE} = 5 V\$

- \$R_1 = 6.1kΩ\$
- \$ R_2 = 1.35kΩ\$
- \$ R_E = 1kΩ \$
- \$ R_3 = 1.5kΩ\$
- \$V_1 = 15 V \$
- \$ I_C = 2mA \$
- \$ U_{BE} = 0.4V \$
- \$ B = 180 \$

Given formula \$r_{BE} \approx \frac {40 mV}{I_B}\$

[image]

First I calculated CE with the use of this formula \$τE ≈ (r_{BE}·C_E ) / β =  1/(2 \pi f) \$

These are my calculations:

$$ I_C = B . I_B $$
$$  rBE = 40mV/ I_B  =  40mV . B / I_C  = 40 . 180 / 2 mA ≈ 4kΩ $$

Let's say the frequency of this amplifier is 1kHz

$$ => τE = 1/(2 \pi f) = 1/(2 \pi 1000)  = 1.519 . 10^{-4} s    $$

Which makes

$$ => C_E = B.τE  / rBE  = 1.519.10^{-4} . 180 / 3600 = 7.6 uF $$

And also

$$τE = (r_E / B ). C1 $$
$$ τE  = (R_E / B )* C1  $$
$$ r_E  = (rBE + B Re) || R1 || R2
       = (4kΩ + 180 * 1kΩ) || 6.1kΩ || 1.35kΩ
       = 1100 Ω
       = 1.1 kΩ  $$

$$ C1 = τE  . B / r_E =>
C1 = ( 1.519 . 10^{-4} s . 180 ) / ( 1.1 * 10^{3} )
      =  0.26 uF $$

Then with this question I could calculate C_2.

What is the minimum size of capacitor C2 if the lower limit frequency should be approx.imately 1000 Hz when the output is loaded with 100 kΩ?

$$τE = R * C2 => C2 = τE / R = 1.519 * 10^{-4}  / 100kΩ = 1.519 nF $$

$$Ue =√( (1+ω²(R1*C1)²) * (1+ω²(R2*C2)²) . (1+ω²(RE*CE)² ))   = 8.5 V  $$

Summary :

- \$C_E = 7.6   uF \$
- \$C_1 = 0.26  uF \$
- \$C_2 = 1.519 nF \$

And with these calculations I can simulate my circuit .

Output in red, input in blue:
[image]

Shouldn't the positive wave of the output voltage be bigger than the positive wave of the input voltage?

Comment: You appear to be powering your circuit with AC from V1 -am I reading that correctly?

Comment: Are you really using a sine wave source as the power supply?

Comment: Sorry my bad  . Forgot to change them . Just wanted to check the simulation with the sin waves

Comment: now reduce the amplitude of your input.

Comment: Is the formula of the input voltage that I wrote incorrect ?

Comment: Your input voltage is way, way too high.

Comment: So according to the simulation it should be lower than 3V ?

Comment: For an amplifier with relatively minimal feedback such as here, start with a small signal (millivolts). Larger signals will distort as g_m varies, even saturating as you see here.

Comment: 3V? 0.1V is probably still too much. Try 0.01V.

Answer (score 1):

The emitter capacitor allows the transistor to have a voltage gain more than 100 times but your input level is way too high at 8.5V peak. So I removed the emitter capacitor and reduced the input level to show that the top of the waveform was clipping because the transistor is biased wrong.

Then I re-biased the transistor and reduced the level again.
[image]